# System.Messaging.MessageQueue and MSMQ COM API interaction

Tags: .net, active-directory, msmq, system.messaging

In *Pro MSMQ* from Apress, it says on p. 26, that queues grouped by the same Service Type GUID can be reached by client applications using "the Directory Service without needing to know their physical location. This is a good mechanism for clustering."

White papers indicate that the .NET MessaginQueueing API is faster than the COM API.  But the .NET classes apparently do not have the lookup capabilities of the COM API. Is it possible to use the COM objects for GUID assignment from the server—and to lookup message queues for clustering purposes from the client—but to switch over to the .NET objects when doing anything else, such as sending messages and reading them?